# Multiple currencies in Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, currency

Is it possible to add a currency drop-down to Expresso Store's front end to change the currency in the back-end?

I understand I can have the values output as integers and provide conversions via JS, but the cart value would still be in the currency set in the cp, and the transaction would also be in that currency, correct?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Store doesn't support multiple currencies. It would require lots of changes to Store (to let you enter each price in each currency), as well as support from your merchant account bank and payment (most merchant accounts don't support multiple currencies).

The best you can do is provide a "live conversion" service for your customers (using javascript), but make it clear they will still be charged in your base currency.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using the Stripe gateway and hacking the build_payment_request method in the PaymentsService class.

You'll want to change this line:

```
$request['currency'] = config_item('store_currency_code');
```

to accept a POST variable:

```
$request['currency'] = $this->ee->input->post('currency', true);
```

Once you've done that, you should be able to pass a [3 letter currency variable](https://support.stripe.com/questions/which-currencies-does-stripe-support) through the checkout form, either through a hidden field, or a select dropdown.

I'm basing my currency field based on the billing address, so that the user is charged the currency of the country that they are located in. Example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="{if billing_country == "US"}USD{if:else}CAD{/if}">
```

Comment: Would this work with other gateways as well you think? It looks promising using Netaxept. How do you deal with pricing though? Do you use dynamic pricing?